# Angular 8: After Deploy: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ma' before initialization

Tags: angular, deployment

I have build an app with Angular8 and work normally with **ng-serve**. 
And Followed the tutorial to deploy on Github with [angular-cli-ghpages](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages)
There is no error showed during **ng deploy/ng build**.
but I got the error message below.
Can't find any similar error...Could anyone help?
[Github Pages Link](https://hhow09.github.io/calendarapi/)

**Error Message**

> ```
> main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ma' before initialization
>     at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1)
>     at l (runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1)
>     at Object.0 (main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1)
>     at l (runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1)
>     at t (runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1)
>     at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1)
>     at main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1
> zUnb @ main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1
> l @ runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1
> 0 @ main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1
> l @ runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1
> t @ runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1
> r @ runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1
> (anonymous) @ main-es2015.6839f58bab9d13b0750c.js:1
> ```

Comment: It's failing at `const ma = Object.assign({}, ma, {production: !0});` . You can't use (i.e. `access`) `ma` in the `Object.assign()` method because `ma` isn't initialized until after this code executes successfully. That's what the error is trying to tell you. You could perhaps try `ng serve --prod=true` and see if you can reproduce and debug it locally?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but might be something wrong with the setting of environment.prod.ts

```
import { environment as common } from './environment';
export const environment = { ...common, production: true };
```

The problem didn't show after directly copy the setting from *environment.ts* and modify production to true.

Comment: I had the same problem and only realized after reaching this page that angular.json replaces the default environment file with the prod one during compilation, so either nothing to import from or a recursive loop. Makes sense now.